# Scala - how to filter fields from nested classes?

Tags: scala

I'm having a class that has nested classes inside of it:

```
object Notes{

case class Notes(node_number: String,
                  name: String,
                  url: String,
                  Datafiles: List[Data])

case class Data(code: Option[String],
                Datafilename: Option[String])
                DataDate: Option[String])
```

I'm trying to basically filter datafiles based on the datafilename.
Meaning, I would like to retrieve the list of all data files, and then filter them based on them ending with .txt.

What I tried:

```
def m1(input: List[Notes]): (Int) = {
    val x =  input.map(x => x.Datafiles)
    val xy = x.filter(_.Datafilename.get.endsWith(".txt")))
}
```

No matter what I try, I unfortunately can't do so. I've tried double filtering but that doesn't let me select `Datafilename` and I'm getting different issues with filtering.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried, preferably along with a sample input/output/error you are getting.

Comment: @jrook added what I've tried

Comment: My bad @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, fixed it. Basically I want to return the number of .txt files I have. I know I can use count, but I need to figure out how to filter these out of the nested classes first

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `map`, use `flatMap`, then use `count` to get the count at the end:

```
def m1(input: List[Notes]): Int =
  input.flatMap(_.Datafiles)
    .count(_.Datafilename.exists(_.endsWith(".txt")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using standard notation this alternative is safe and efficient.

```
final case class Notes(
    nodeNumber: String,
    name: String,
    url: String,
    dataFiles: List[Data]
)

final case class Data(
    code: Option[String],
    dataFilename: Option[String],
    dataDate: Option[String]
)

def m1(input: List[Notes]): Int =
  input
    .iterator
    .flatMap(_.dataFiles)
    .flatMap(_.dataFilename)
    .count(_.endsWith(".csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `get` on an `Option` can be dangerous since it will crash if it is `None`. A more concise solution that also utilizes `Option` combinators could be:

```scala
def m1(input: List[Notes]): Int =
  input.flatMap(_.Datafiles)
    .filter(_.Datafilename.map(_.endsWith(".txt")).getOrElse(false))
    .length
```